# Sort PHP array of string (line) with two substring

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I wanted to sort php array based on `CRITICAL` , `WARNING` ,`INFO` sub string and then  `CRITICAL` , `WARNING` ,`INFO` sub array should be sorted again with the time stamp value contains in each line of string in acsending order.
Basically at the end I need array to be sorted with `CRITICAL` 1st with time stamp sorted then `WARNING` and then `INFO` so on..

```
$keys = array_keys($eventinfo["message"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
    $key = ($keys[$i]);
    $perNode = $eventinfo["message"][$key];
    $arrTmp = explode("\n", $perNode);
    $t = count($arrTmp);
    $tmp = 0;
    while ($t) {
        $t--;
        if ($arrTmp[$tmp] != "") {
            $cumltvArray[] = "<a href='#'>" . $key. "</a> : </br>".$arrTmp[$tmp];
        }
        $tmp++;
    }
}
$result_str = events_print($cumltvArray);
// $cumltvArray is the one which I am passing to events_print
```

Comment: nothing is clear....

Comment: Please provide your array format

Comment: $keys= (array_keys($eventinfo["message"]));
   for ( $i = 0; $i < count($keys);  $i++ ){
      $key = ($keys[$i]);
      $perNode= $eventinfo["message"][$key];
      $arrTmp=explode("\n",$perNode);
      $t=count($arrTmp);
      $tmp = 0;
      while($t){
         $t--;
         if($arrTmp[$tmp]!=""){
            $cumltvArray[] ="<a href='#'>". $key."</a> : </br>".$arrTmp[$tmp];
         }
         $tmp++;
      }
   }
   $result_str = events_print($cumltvArray);
 $cumltvArray is the one which I am passing to events_print

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow because it is Unclear and doesn't contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

First, define a function that turns the urgency of a line into a number.

```
function urgency($line)
{
    if (strpos($line, 'INFO') !== false) {
        return 1;
    } elseif (strpos($line, 'WARNING') !== false) {
        return 2;
    } elseif (strpos($line, 'CRITICAL') !== false) {
        return 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, assuming each element of your array contains a line of the file, you need to apply a decorator to keep the sort stable; see also [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php/17365409#17365409) on the subject:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$element, $index) {
    $element = array($element, $index); // decorate
});
```

After applying the decorator, you sort the array; I'm using a stable comparison helper:

```
function stablecmp($fn)
{
    return function($a, $b) use ($fn) {
        if (($tmp = call_user_func($fn, $a[0], $b[0])) != 0) {
            return $tmp;
        } else {
            return $a[1] - $b[1];
        }
    };
}

usort($array, stablecmp(function($a, $b) {
    return urgency($b) - urgency($a);
}));
```

Finally, undecorate the array to produce the end result:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$element) {
    $element = $element[0];
});
```

Comment: Jack, could you explain the syntaxt of the last part of your code? The usort part. Never seen PHP written this way. What does function($a,$b) do? How does it this work? I also dont understand your return statement. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Bolli I'm using [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: Thanks Jack http://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/ja%cd%a2ck  nice answer , can it be sorted with the time stamp contains in the line aswell with same complexity with recent time first in order of CRITICAL-->Warning-->INFO

Answer (score 0):

Getting CRITICAL on the sorted order

```
function my_cmp($a, $b){
 $pieces_a = explode("CRITICAL", $a);
 $pieces_b = explode("CRITICAL", $b);

 if(!isset($pieces_a[1]) && isset($pieces_b[1])) {
    return 1;
 }
 elseif(!isset($pieces_b[1]) && isset($pieces_a[1])) {
    return -1;
 }
 elseif(!isset($pieces_a[1]) && !isset($pieces_b[1])) {
    return 0;
 }
 return strcasecmp($pieces_a[1], $pieces_b[1]);
}
usort($arr, "my_cmp");
```

But this can only sort if the each line has non spaces I mean single word,.

Any other solution curious to know?